# Python3: socket web server request cannot be printed

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, websocket, webserver

I am creating a socket web server (without using httpServer is must), my job is to print out an 'index.html' to the localhost from the request. I could print the request normally, but it won't be shown on my browser.

Server:

```
from socket import *
def main():
    serversocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    try :
        serversocket.bind(('localhost',9000))
        serversocket.listen(5)
        while(1):
            clientsocket, address = serversocket.accept()

            req = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
            pieces = req.split("\n")
            if ( len(pieces) > 0 ) : print(pieces[0])
            #Get the content of the file
            fin = open('index.html')
            content = fin.read()
            fin.close()
            
            print(content) #This works normally

            data = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" + content
            clientsocket.sendall(data.encode())
            clientsocket.shutdown(SHUT_WR)
    except KeyboardInterrupt :
        print("\nShut down\n")
    except Exception as exc :
        print("Error:\n")
        print(exc)

    serversocket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

if I just do `data += "<html><body>Hello World</body></html>\r\n\r\n"`, it works normally. I have also tried to change some formats in html file but it didn't work.

Client:

```
import socket

clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientSock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9000))
cmd = 'GET http://127.0.0.1/index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n'.encode()
clientSock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = clientSock.recv(1024)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode(),end='')

clientSock.close()
```

This is the 'index.html' just in case.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is neither a proper HTTP request (host header missing, absolute form instead of [origin form](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-5.3.1)) nor a proper HTTP response (end of response header must be empty line), i.e. something like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n`.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich it works as soon as added one more `\r\n`, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to bufferize the server response because if the data doesn't fit in one chuck you cannot read the whole page.

You can do something like that:

```
# retrieve server response
chunk = skt.recv(4096)
if chunk:
    buffer = b''  // data sent in bytes on the socket
    while True:
        buffer += chunk
        if buffer.find(CONTROL_FLAG) > 0:
            buffer = buffer.replace(CONTROL_FLAG, b'')
            break
        chunk = skt.recv(4096)
```

In my case I used a string flag (CONTROL_FLAG) to know the end of the response. I hope this idea can be of help to you.